# Database Url not specified even though I have a liquibase.properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, liquibase

I am trying to run my migrations using liquibase but for somo reason my pom file is not finding my properties file. When I run the update command I get the following error

```
The database URL has not been specified either as a parameter or in a properties file.
```

I am using the exections tag because I want to have more that one database connected to my application.
Before I added that tag everything worked fine

### pom File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.petapilot</groupId>
    <artifactId>migrations</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Migrations</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <start-class>com.petapilot.migrations.MigrationsApplication</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>postgre-update</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase_postgre.properties</propertyFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>mysql-update</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score -2):

When using executions, you must tell Maven which goal to run, and which phase is responsible for running the goal, as described in the [general plugin config docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag).

When you specify the properties file in a top-level `<configuration>` block, it applies for all plugin executions.

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <configuration>
      <phase>[Maven phase]</phase>
      <goals>
          <goal>[plugin goal to run]</goal>
      </goals>
      <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: is there any difference between the phases and the goals values?

Comment: Definitely. There are many goals in the [liquibase-maven-plugin](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/home.html). Some may be bound to specific phases by default; this is usually indicated in plugin's goal documentation.. Research "Maven lifecycle" to learn about phases and how they are sequenced. I don't know much about this specific plugin, but in general all Maven plugin executions need to define a goal.

Comment: Shouldn't goals be in the same level as configuration?

Comment: Tried what you said but still getting the same error(updated my question)